# Publishing blazor wasm 404 errors

Tags: blazor, github-pages, publish, blazor-webassembly, azure-static-web-app

Blazor app builds without errors. When I publish it to azure static web app or to github pages I get the same not found errors. Any thoughts how you would approach this problem ?
All files except these load with 200 code:

```
KernelTraceControl.dll          404    fetch    blazor.webassembly.js:1
KernelTraceControl.Win61.dll    404    fetch    blazor.webassembly.js:1
msdia140.dll                    404    fetch    blazor.webassembly.js:1
```

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**

Comment: @Rob, how would you produce a minimal reproducible example in this situation, assuming you can't share all your code and sharing parts of code won't do any good, because it won't be enough to reproduce the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Making a new Blazor project and copying all the files from the old one solved the issue and I was able to publish to azure static web apps. The project file is exactly the same with the same target framework net5.0 and references.